# Selenium Python: delete_all_cookies() is not deleting all the cookies stored

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

There is this website : http://justnotepad.com/
Here we can write notes and it will store it in browser's storage so if we reload/reopen the page again it restores the previous notes.

So I want to open this website 3 times in same Browser Instance without closing it by opening and closing new tabs.
Between Closing and Opening of Tabs `browser.delete_all_cookies()` is executed.
But the website is still able to fetch previous notes.

The following code is working for http://temp-mail.org after each load the mail address changes. Which means the cookies are getting deleted. But can't understand why it isn't working for  http://justnotepad.com/

My Full Code:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path=cpath)
for i in range(2):

    browser.get('http://justnotepad.com')
    t=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="editable_text_box"]/textarea[@name="editable_text"][@id="editable_text"]')

    t.send_keys(Keys.ENTER + "This is a new line")

    '''
    browser.get("https://temp-mail.org")
    print(len(browser.window_handles))
    #print(browser.get_cookie('mail'))
    eid=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="mail"]').get_attribute('value')
    print(eid)
    '''
    print("current:",browser.current_window_handle)
    browser.execute_script("window.open('', 'new_tab')")
    print(len(browser.window_handles))
    next_tab=browser.window_handles[len(browser.window_handles)-1]
    print(next_tab)
    print(browser.title)
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    #browser.delete_cookie('mail')
    browser.close()
    print(len(browser.window_handles))

    browser.switch_to_window(next_tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but like when you inject cookies and refresh the page for them to load, the same goes for deleting.
Try to refresh the page and see if that makes a difference.

```
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(seconds)  # Wait for it to load
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, the information is not stored in the cookies. It is in the browser's Local Storage.

To show:

1. browse to http://justnotepad.com/
2. Open Dev Tools (F12)
3. Use the Application tab
4. Click on Local Storage
5. Click on `justnotepad.com` leaf
6. Write something in the notepad.
7. Watch the key and value twitch.
8. Delete the note. Watch the key and value twitch.

Comment: I don't think this is addressing OP's issue since he is using selenium to automate the process, he'll want a coded solution that can perform the same. Maybe you can provide a code in deleting the data store in local storage?